# matchit: Specified caliper still matches everyone!

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

Suppose we are using the matchit function from the MatchIt package in R, as in the following example given in the package,

`m.out1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree + married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, distance = "glm", method = "nearest", replace=FALSE, caliper = NULL, ratio = 1)`

Suppose now, you want to match only those treated patients that are within a specified caliper = 0.1 (in terms of propensity scores) of the control, and otherwise leave them unmatched, I would do,

`m.out2 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree + married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, distance = "glm", method = "nearest", replace = FALSE, caliper = 0.1, ratio = 1)`

In both cases I get the same matching result, in terms of sample size. I am confused by this, as even those outside the caliper are being matched. Note that, this was working the way I understand before, but is giving different results now. Please let me know if there have been any updates that I am missing.

Thank you!
############################################################################
Adding to Noah's comment below,

`m.out1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree + married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, distance = "glm", method = 'nearest', replace = FALSE, ratio = 1)`

`summary(m.out1)$nn`

[image: Output1]

`m.out2 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree + married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, distance = "glm", method = "nearest", replace = FALSE, caliper = 0.1, ratio = 1)`

`summary(m.out2)$nn`

[image: Output2]

Comment: What version of `MatchIt` are you using? On version 4.5.3 the caliper works as intended.

Comment: I am using version 4.5.1

Comment: I do not get this issue when using version 4.5.1. Can you provide the output and the code that generated that output to demonstrate the problem? E.g., the call to `summary()` and the output of that call. Please make sure the call to `summary()` is included.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question above, to reflect the output

Comment: Thank you. That is odd but I cannot replicate those results in any recent version of `MatchIt`. Please try updating to a recent version and trying again. If the problem is still occurring, please submit a GitHub issue so we can discuss it further. In the future, GitHub issues are a better place for bug reports and questions than CV, especially since this is more about programming than statistics.

Comment: I saw the same error and opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/163